# Multi threading delays the whole program and loads everything at once, need a proper algorithm

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my code for a card deck on a table, I've never used Threads before and don't know how to use. 
I need them to show up with a 2s delay between each of them.

Initially all the cards are .setVisible(false);

```
try {
   Card1.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card2.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card3.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card4.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card5.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card6.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card7.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card8.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card9.setVisible(true);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Card10.setVisible(true);
   }

catch (InterruptedException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(TableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

Comment: I cannot see any multi threads here...

Comment: As per what you are trying to achieve, multi threading will not help you to get what you want. Because it will mix up the order. Unless you want to show the cards in a jumbled pattern...

Comment: So what happens? Why doesn't this work. I am going to guess, that after 18 seconds all of the cards are suddenly set to visible.

Comment: An MCVE would be nice, but I suspect what is happening here is that all this is happening on the EDT thread, meaning that nothing will be redrawn until AFTER the block is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a multi-threading issue.

But you can achieve this by storing the `Card` objects in a `List` and the iterating it.

```
List<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<>();
cardsList.add(Card1);
...
cardsList.add(Card10);
try {
      for(Card card : cardsList) {
          card.setVisible(true);
          Thread.sleep(2000);
      }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(TableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address op's issue at all. It would be an improvement, but it would suffer from the same problem op is having.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), this will handle your multi-threading and let actions take place with at scheduled times.

```
long delay = 2000;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Card1.setVisible(true); 
    }
}, delay);
timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Card2.setVisible(true); 
    }
}, delay*2);
```

The first task will run after 2000ms delay, the second task after 4000ms delay. I stopped there because it is cumbersome to write everything out. You should consider using a list as the other answer suggested.

Incidentally, the timer will manage a thread for you. I think your actual problem was you were blocking the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `DelayQueue` for printing result with some delay.

Code Example:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        DelayQueue<DeleyedItem> dq = new DelayQueue();
        DeleyedItem ob1 = new DeleyedItem(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2), Card1);
        DeleyedItem ob2 = new DeleyedItem(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(4), Card2);
        DeleyedItem ob3 = new DeleyedItem(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(6), Card3);

        dq.offer(ob1);
        dq.offer(ob2);
        dq.offer(ob3);

        while (!dq.isEmpty()) {
            DeleyedItem item = dq.take();
            item.visible();
        }

    }
}

class DeleyedItem implements Delayed {
    public final Long delayMillis;
    public final Long expireTimeMillis;
    private Card card;

    DeleyedItem(long delayMillis,Card card) {
        this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
        this.expireTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayMillis;
        this.card=card;
    }

    @Override
    public final int compareTo(Delayed o) {
        long diffMillis = getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) - o.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        diffMillis = Math.min(diffMillis, 1);
        diffMillis = Math.max(diffMillis, -1);
        return (int) diffMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public final long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        long delayMillis = expireTimeMillis - System.currentTimeMillis();
        return unit.convert(delayMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void visible() {
        card.setVisible(true);
    }
```

You can use `lockSupport` util to park the thread for certain time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card1.setVisible(true);

        await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Card2.setVisible(true);
        await(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Card3.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void await(long time, TimeUnit unit) {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(unit.toNanos(time));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think this is better than `Thread.sleep`? This still wouldn't solve ops problem because they are 'parking' the EDT.

Comment: It is using  private static final sun.misc.Unsafe UNSAFE;  // Hotspot implementation via intrinsics API.Use by all concurrent API and better than Thread.sleep which has its own limitation

Comment: It wouldn't solve the problem, and it offers no guarantee that it will actually 'park' for the required amount of time.

Comment: Yes you are correct it will park but no guarantee it will park the amount of time.How about using a delay queue so it will return after the time delayed